# Debian package not including files; runs install during build

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package

I'm creating a Debian package for my application using dh/debuild, following [Ubuntu's PackagingGuide/Complete](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) but I'm having some trouble. I think it has to do with the structure of my Makefile. The source Makefile is:

```
install:
    mkdir -p /usr/share/getbooru
    cp -av * /usr/share/getbooru
    ln -s /usr/share/getbooru/getbooru /usr/bin/getbooru
remove:
    rm -rv /usr/share/getbooru /usr/bin/getbooru
```

The application is written in PHP so no compiling is needed. After running `debuild -S` to build the source Debian package, I then use `debian/rules binary` to create the binary package. These are the problems:

- the above install procedure (Makefile `install` target) is run during package build
- the resulting package does not contain my application files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to change the upstream Makefile so instead of installing to /usr/share/* it installs to debian/$packagename/usr/share.